# PIC32MX795F512H Ethernet signals

Tags: poe

Hey guys I am designing a PoE circuit board and the microcontroller that I want to use (PIC32MX795F512H) seems to be missing some pins to connect my data lines or it's not clear to me where the lines should go. From the Ethernet cable I need to connect TX+,TX-,RX+,RX- to the microcontroller but the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001156J.pdf) doesn't indicate which pins are for positives and negative on the Ethernet transmit and receive port. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: The LAN8740 from Microchip makes this pretty easy, there are multiple reference designs available from Microchip, just look for the PIC32MX Starter Kit or the PIC32MX Discovery Board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be connected directly, you need a PHY chip to convert the MII interface to physical copper interface.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was missing from my circuit.

Comment: @be-ee - Probably missing the magnetics too ... ?

Comment: @brhans I have the transformer in the circuit, but thanks for the reminder!